# Get avatar using Skype API on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, skype

I use this command to get avatar of user on mac osx app

```
[SkypeAPI sendSkypeCommand:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GET USER %@ AVATAR 1 %@", skypeId, path]];
```

But this has error that is

> ERROR 1 General syntax error

I search this solution but it's for window

http://community.skype.com/t5/General-Discussion/My-Profile-Pic/m-p/200606#M2303

How can I solve this problem on MacOS?